# Wicket download link

Tags: wicket

On the Wicket page I have an image (AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.INDICATOR)  which is shown on submit and then i start a AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior to monitor a file.

Now I also have a DownloadLink to download the same file. However after download the image which I mentioned above (which is rotating) stops rotating. Is there a solution to this issue? I am new to wicket. Please suggest.

`````
public LoggingPage() {

 Form<Void> form;
    this.add(form = new Form<Void>("resourceForm") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onSubmit() {
            submit();
        }
    });
   add(new DownloadLink("downloadButton", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<File>()
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public File getObject()
        {
            File file;
            try
            {
                file = new File(LoggingPage.this.fileDetail.getLocation());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return file;
        }
    }));

}//cons ends

 private void submit() {
    if (this.serverDetail != null && this.fileType != null && this.fileDetail != null)
    {
        if (this.fileViewer != null)
        {
            this.repeater.removeAll();
        }
        File file = new File(this.fileDetail.getLocation());
        file = new File("C:/ueshome/logs/safe.log");
        this.fileViewer = new FileViewer(file);
        this.fileViewer.startTailing();
        log.debug("load of allLog: " + this.fileViewer.getOldLog());
        buildItem(this.fileViewer.getOldLog().getLog().toString());
        this.container.add(new AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1))
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPostProcessTarget(final AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                target.appendJavascript("$('#container').scrollTop( 999999999 )");
                log.debug("onPostProcessTarget: " + LoggingPage.this.fileViewer.hashCode() + "at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
                final FileAttributes fileAttributes = LoggingPage.this.fileViewer.getNewLog();
                String newLog = fileAttributes.getLog().toString();
                log.debug("nextlog inside load()");
                if (newLog != null && newLog.trim().length() > 0)
                {
                    log.debug("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~````*****:" + newLog);
                    log.debug("String.valueOf(fileAttributes.getSize()))~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~````*****:" + String.valueOf(fileAttributes.getSize()));
                    log.debug("String.valueOf(fileAttributes.getLastModified()): " + String.valueOf(fileAttributes.getLastModified()));

                    if (LoggingPage.this.repeater.getSizeInBytes() >= logSize)
                    {
                        LoggingPage.this.repeater.removeAll();
                    }
                    Component item = buildItem(newLog);

                    target.prependJavascript(String.format(
                            "var item=document.createElement('%s');item.id='%s';Wicket.$('%s').appendChild(item);",
                            "div", item.getMarkupId(), LoggingPage.this.container.getMarkupId()));

                    //                      LoggingPage.this.imgContainer.setVisible(true);
                    //                      target.addComponent(LoggingPage.this.imgContainer);
                    target.addComponent(item);

                    target.appendJavascript("$('#fileAttributesContainer').show(); ");
                    target.appendJavascript("$('#container').scrollTop( 999999999 )");
                    target.appendJavascript("$('#imageContainer').show(); ");

                }
                else
                {
                    target.appendJavascript("$('#fileAttributesContainer').show(); ");
                    target.appendJavascript("$('#container').scrollTop( 999999999 )");
                    target.appendJavascript("$('#imageContainer').show(); ");
                }

                target.appendJavascript("alert('You are in Ajax Self')");
            }
`````

Comment: Can you please give a sample of your code?

Comment: i have added the sample code. appreciate your quick response.

Comment: In the future, when adding code, simply edit your question instead of posting it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First I have to admit that I have no idea right now what could be wrong with your code. It looks rather different than how I would solve your task.

As I understand you want to have a image (an animated gif) that is animated after the user hits the submit button, right. And it should stop the animation after a certain condition is met (file generation finished etc.). Also you want to have a download link for your file.

What I would do is

- use a animated gif that will be shown
- add a AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior that checks your file and if a certain condition is met it changes the image (maybe by changing the image itself, sets the visibility of the image or by changing some css attribute for the image container)
- for the file download I would use an ajax button or if nothing should be changed on your side a normal link that delivers an resource stream for your file

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Can you please provide some example code for point 3 above (for the file download I would use an ajax button or if nothing should be changed on your side a normal link that delivers an resource stream for your file 
)

Comment: Sorry for this late answer.

I provided a simple example on github: https://github.com/magomi/wicket-download-sample

It provides an label and an download link. When you klick on the link, the download will be initiated AND the label will be changed via ajax. The core part of this (the AjaxDownloadBehavior) is documented in the wicket wiki: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/ajax-update-and-file-download-in-one-blow.html